# PromiseKit doesn't compile with Swift 2 and Xcode 7

Tags: xcode, swift2, promisekit

This is the error I am seeing when I try to build my project after installing PromiseKit.

```
Cannot import module being compiled.
```

This is what my PodFile contains to install PromiseKit.

```
pod 'PromiseKit', :git => 'https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit.git', :branch => 'swift-2.0-minimal-changes'
```

I tried having the following statement in PodFile, but it was throwing many more compilation errors, so I tried the above statement.

```
pod "PromiseKit", "~> 2.0"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug in the minimal-changes branch. The `swift-2.0-beta5` branch will work, though it may require more changes in your project. I will fix the bug in `minimal-changes`.

Edit: Fixed: https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit/commit/d969c72b9f959d7fb5a68f117142c79bf0c3098d

Comment: Thanks for great product, and really great customer service :P

Comment: ^seriously. Thank you @mxcl.